# Express session not storing session

Tags: express, reactjs, session-cookies, passport.js, express-session

So I'm building a web application using isomorphic-redux and React.js. I'm currently trying to get basic authentication working using passport in Node.js. However I have hit a problem in which my cookie session does not seem to be loaded in browser when I try to login.

Here is a cut down version of the code I've written so far.

**Server.js**

```
import Express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import expressSession from 'express-session';

import serverConfig from './config';

const app = new Express();

// Apply body Parser and server public assets and routes
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '20mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: true }));
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: serverConfig.sessionSecret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

import pp from './passport';
pp();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**passport.js**

```
import passport from 'passport';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import path from 'path';

import User from './models/user.model';

import local from './strategies/local';

const pp =  () => {
    // Serialize sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // Deserialize sessions
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findOne({
            _id: id
        }, '-salt -password', function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    local();
}

export default pp;
```

**./strategies/local.js**

```
import passport from 'passport';
import passportLocal from 'passport-local';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
const User = mongoose.model('User');

const local = () => {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password'
    },
    (username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Unknown user or invalid password'
          });
        }
        if (!user.authenticate(password)){
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Unknown user or invalid password'
          });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));
}

export default local;
```

When I login in it is able to serialise the session, however since I'm guessing, the session does not get stored, it does not deserialise the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sessions to be persistent, you need to tell the `express-session` module where to store them. First, you need to build a store:

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);
var oneHour = 3600;
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-session-store',
    touchAfter: oneHour
});
```

This creates a mongoDB store using `connect-mongo` - I'm sure this can be done with `mongoose` as well but I don't know how so I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader :-)

Then you can tell the express-session module to use this store:

```
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: serverConfig.sessionSecret,
  store: sessionStore,    // <---- added store information!
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```